# Creating a Dictionary of Timers

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, timer

I'm writing a scheduler for our application which pulls its tasks out of our central database. It runs a variety of things from external 'modules' of our application to custom SQL scripts.

I have declared as follows:

```
Dim ScheduleList As New DataTable
Dim WithEvents Actions As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
Dim WithEvents Timers As New Dictionary(Of String, Timers.Timer)()
```

And my code that sets everything up is here.

```
Private Sub RunScheduleTasks()

    Dim result() As DataRow = ScheduleList.Select("TriggerType = 0 AND IsEnabled = 1") 'External Calls
    For Each row As DataRow In result
        Dim i As Integer = row(0)
        Actions.Add("action" + i.ToString, row(9).ToString)
        WriteLog("Action Added: " + i.ToString, "INFORMATION")

        Dim T As New System.Timers.Timer
        With T
            .Interval = Convert.ToInt32(row(7).ToString) * 1000
            AddHandler T.Elapsed, Sub(sender, e)
                                      Process.Start(row(9).ToString)
                                      WriteLog(row(9).ToString, "INFORMATION")
                                  End Sub

        End With
        Timers.Add("timer" + i.ToString, T)

        WriteLog("Timer Added: " + i.ToString, "INFORMATION")

        Timers("timer" + i.ToString).Start()
    Next
    WriteLog("Actions: " + Actions.Count.ToString, "INFORMATION")
    WriteLog("Timers: " + Timers.Count.ToString, "INFORMATION")

End Sub
```

My Issue is that it only seems to run whatever the last created object was, My output logging shows several items in there however on inspecting them they all display Void _Lambda$__1()

Regards
Mike

Comment: Your code is suffering from variable capture in a loop. Normally vs produces a warning for this. Rename your loop variable r and on the next line add `Dim row = r` then it'll capture the actual value you need instead of the final one.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks that's nailed it! Something so small. Are you able to explain the difference between declaring it within in loop as opposed to using the loop variable?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2007/07/26/closures-in-vb-part-5-looping/

Comment: One more reason why you should treat visual studio warnings as errors.

Comment: Awesome cheers! :)